# A question about the backward orbit and forward orbit of a rational map in 1-dimensional projective space

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

I am a bit puzzled about some probable implication in a paper.
Let $\varphi:\mathbb{P}^1_K\to \mathbb{P}^1_K$ be a rational map, where $K$ is a number field and let $\alpha\in K$ be such that $\varphi(\alpha)\neq\infty$. Then is it true that $\alpha$ is an exceptional point (backward orbit of $\alpha$ under $\varphi$ is finite) implies $\alpha$ is a preperiodic point (forward orbit of $\alpha$ under $\varphi$ is finite)? If this is not true providing an example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha_0=\alpha$, and for each $n\ge1$, choose a point $$\alpha_n\in\phi^{-1}(\alpha_{n-1})\subset \mathbb P^1(\overline K).$$ (The map $\phi$ is surjective on $\mathbb P^1(\overline K)$.) The points $\alpha_n$ are in the backward orbit of $\alpha$, which you have assumed is finite. Hence I can find some $m>n\ge0$ such that $\alpha_m=\alpha_n$. Then
$$
\alpha = \phi^m(\alpha_m) = \phi^m(\alpha_n) = \phi^{m-n}\circ\phi^n(\alpha_n)
= \phi^{m-n}(\alpha).
$$
Hence $\alpha$ is periodic.